# How can I refactor this angular directive with a custom $resource factory method?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following $resource factory:

```
app.factory "FeatureKey", ($resource) ->

  $resource "/api/v1/feature_keys/:id", { id: "@id" }
```

In a directive, I use it like so:

```
@search = (term) ->
  FeatureKey.query(name: term).$promise.then (keys) =>
    if keys.length > 0
      @keys = keys
    else
      @keys = [{id: 0, name: term}]
    @current.key = @keys[0]
```

What I'd like to is move most of the logic into the $resource factory so that my directive method would look like so:

```
@search = (term) ->
  FeatureKey.search(term).$promise.then (keys) =>
    @keys = keys
    @current.key = @keys[0]
```

Comment: Ok, just changed the desired refactor. What about like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have your factory return an object with a `search` method instead of returning a resource:

```
app.factory "FeatureKey", ($resource) ->
  r = $resource "/api/v1/feature_keys/:id", { id: "@id" }

  search: (term) ->
    r.query(name: term).$promise.then (keys) ->
      if keys.length then keys else [{id: 0, name: term}]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
FeatureKey.search(term).then (keys) =>
  @keys = keys
  @current.key = @keys[0]
```